# Cannot write to SSHFS mount in user namespace created with "unshare -c -m --keep-caps bash"

Tags: linux, filesystems, sshfs

### Background

Ultimately I am trying to mount a remote filesystem in a kubernetes pod on a self-hosted cluster that uses Docker as a container runtime. The process running in the pod determines the mount at runtime and might mount/unmount/remount filesystems at runtime, so as far as I am aware using PVC/PV is out of the question. Furthermore, I want to use SSHFS because it requires minimal setup on the remote side (which I might not control in all use-cases).

In order to allow the containers to perform mount operations I am using a custom seccomp profile that allows the container to perform the needed system calls (mount, umount, unshare, etc.). I also expose /dev/fuse to the container.

### The issue

I can succesfully mount a remote folder using sshfs in a container after runnning: `unshare -c -m --keep-caps bash`. I can read the folder, but I cannot write to it.

On my own machine I run into the same issue when using unshare. Without using unshare I can mount the filesystem using:
`sshfs sshtestuser@example.com:/some/remote/folder /tmp/sshfs/`
This allows me to read and write to /tmp/sshfs.

After running `unshare -c -m --keep-caps`

and subsequently running

`sshfs sshtestuser@example.com:/some/remote/folder /tmp/sshfs/`

I can read /tmp/sshfs (within the user namespace), but not write to it.

This is not a permission issue on the remote server, as I can write to the folder when not using "unshare". I can also write to the mountpoint before issuing the mount command in the namespace.

I have tried to add the `-o rw` and `-o allow_other` switches to the mount command, but they do not seem to have any effect. I have also tried to mount at a different location but that also had no effect.

I am not sure how to further debug this issue or how to proceed.